# integral of trace function

Tags: normal-distribution, matrices, integration

How can I compute the below integral?

$$
\int e^{-1/2*tr[(\mu\mu^T-\mu m^T-m\mu^T)\Sigma]}d\mu
$$

in which $\mu \in R^{n},m \in R^{n},\Sigma \in R^{n*n}$ and $tr(.)$ is trace of matrix.

I have problem with integral join with trace. how can I solve it?

Comment: Would it help to recognize that $\operatorname{tr}(\mu\mu^\prime\Sigma)=\mu^\prime\Sigma\mu$ (assuming $\mu$ is a *column* vector)?

Comment: I knew your statement but i change $\mu'\Sigma\mu$ to $tr(\mu\mu'\Sigma)$ to compute the integration easier. ($\mu$ and $m$ both are $n*1$ vectors)

Comment: That tells us you are unfamiliar with the multivariate Gaussian integral.  That's fine--you can look it up in various places, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_and_functional_generalization.

Comment: sorry i think you are right thanks alot